# Unauthorized: Token missing

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui

trying to implement swagger 2 in Xml based Spring MVC project.

when trying to hit http://localhost:8080/myapp/v2/api-docs
throws an error "HTTP Status 401 - Unauthorized: Token missing"

pom.xml::

```
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

swaggerconfig.java ::

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

webconfig.java::

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override 
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```

Springconfig.java::

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String[] AUTH_WHITELIST = {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**",
                        "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
    }
}
```

ApplicationContext.xml::

```
    <mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/"/>
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/"/> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```